# How to check the date string contains millisecond in it or not in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, datetime, nsdate, nsdateformatter

In my application in one scenario me getting date string say 12/15/2014 13:23:45 (MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss) and 12/15/2014 13:23:45:928 (MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS) that is I am getting a date string with milliseconds and a date string without milliseconds. Can any one help me in checking millisecond is present in the given string or not by assigning a boolean to true if millisecond is present and assign the boolean value to false when millisecond is not present. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Is the bool your main goal? Or do you need a NSDate and want to figure out which NSDateFormatter to use?

In both cases you can convert with both NSDateFormatters. Only one of them will work, the other will return nil because its dateFormat is wrong.

Since you didn't specify a language I wrote a Swift version of that code:

```
var date: NSDate?
var hasMilliSeconds = false


let string = "12/15/2014 13:23:45:928"
//let string = "12/15/2014 13:23:45"


let dfWithMilliSeconds = NSDateFormatter()
dfWithMilliSeconds.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS"
if let d = dfWithMilliSeconds.dateFromString(string) {
    date = d
    hasMilliSeconds = true
}

let dfWithoutMilliSeconds = NSDateFormatter()
dfWithoutMilliSeconds.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
if let d = dfWithoutMilliSeconds.dateFromString(string) {
    date = d
    hasMilliSeconds = false
}

println("Has milliseconds: \(hasMilliSeconds)")
println("Date \(date?.descriptionWithLocale(NSLocale.currentLocale()))")
```

Comment: Note that `NSDateFormatter` is quite expensive to create, so if this code is going to be called frequently, you'd better cache the formatters.

Comment: Yes, that's just the naive implementation. In a real world app you would perform the second attempt only if the first one has failed. And you would order the two checks in a way that only the first check is performed most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your date in string and calculate length of string and check if length is less than or equal to your without milisecond length then it is not with milisecond else with milisecond

Answer (score 0):

You set your NSDateFormatter as "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss:SSS"
then convert the string to date, if you get some result then, be sure the string contains milliseconds part in the string, but if you get nil as result then be sure that the string does not contain milliseconds part 
The code is as follows

```
 NSString *str1 = @"12/15/2014 13:23:45:928";

NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

[formatter setCalendar:[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:@"gregorian"]];
NSLocale *local=[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[formatter setLocale:local];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss:SSS"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:str1];
```

If you find it useful, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try Implementing Following Code

```
NSString *stringDate = @"12/15/2014 13:12:45:967";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS"];

NSDate *newDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:stringDate];

if (newDate == nil){
    NSLog(@"Miliseconds not found");
}else{
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"SSS"];
    NSLog(@"Miliseconds found %@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:newDate]);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Calculate the length  of the string and find out whether milliseconds is present or not. Also, you can count the number of colons in it and find out.